# Proper way to assign a new array to an existing array

Tags: java

Taking into consideration that Java operates off of pass-by-value. Which of the following would be deemed the most conventional/correct way to assign a new array value to an already existing array:

1:

```java
 int[] x = {1,2};

    public static int[] changeValue(int[] arr) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            arr[i]*=2;
        }
        return arr;
    }

    changeValue(x);
```

2:

```java
 int[] x = {1,2};

    public static int[] changeValue(int[] arr) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            arr[i]*=2;
        }
        return arr;
    }

    x = changeValue(x);
```

3:

```java
 int[] x = {1,2};

    public static void changeValue(int[] arr) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            arr[i]*=2;
        }
    }

    changeValue(x);
```

Thanks.

Comment: The third one works. You're passing a copy of the reference but what you're modifying is the contents of the actual object.

Comment: They all work, but I would have thought that just conventionally the second one would of made the most sense?

Comment: @Danny have you considered the `Stream` option?

Comment: @LppEdd The stream option does seem to be rather good, however I was more interested in figuring out which of the 3 options I listed was the most conventional.

Comment: @Danny imho the third one. A `void` return type explicitly says that the input array will be modified. Returning `int[]` might be misleading. A user might think a new array is returned, while it is not. But still, prefer immutability.

Answer (score 2):

Either is fine. As for code guidelines you can stick to the native java methods e.g. [`Collections#reverse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse(java.util.List)) does not return anything. It mutates the passed object. So it really depends on exactly what the method does.

So in your case I would go with the third version.

Answer (score 2):

Actually I would prefer return a new array instead of modified existing one:

```
public static int[] changeValue(int[] arr) {
    int[] newArr = new int[arr.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        newArr[i] = arr[i] * 2;
    }
    return newArr;
}
```

See more about [immutability importance](https://dzone.com/articles/the-importance-of-immutability-in-java)

And [Why is immutability so important in software development](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-immutability-so-important-in-software-development)

Comment: Or perhaps keeping the same method, but adding arr = Arrays.copyOf(arr, arr.length); instead of declaring a new variable.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `Stream` is the cleanest way

```
public static int[] changeValue(final int[] arr) {
   return IntStream.of(arr)
                   .map(i -> i *= 2)
                   .toArray();
}
```

This will also let you pass in a customized/variable transformation function

```
public static int[] changeValue(final int[] arr, final IntUnaryOperator function) {
    return IntStream.of(arr)
                    .map(function)
                    .toArray();
}
```

---

```
final int[] result1 = changeValue(ints, i -> i *= 2);
final int[] result2 = changeValue(ints, i -> i /= 4);
```

Immutability, clean code, and parallelizable (`.parallel()`) for big arrays.